Android XML TextSize scales differently from Compose Text FontSize?
So I'm modifying a project that has existing XML code, but designing a new page with ComposeView in the same project.
Here is a textview style I've used for a header style.
<style name="PageHeaders" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/ui_display_bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    </style>

 ...

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/page_header_top_margin" <!-- 20dp -->
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/page_header_bottom_margin" <!-- 10dp -->
        android:text="Main Header Text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ui_display_bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

and here is the text compose version
 val fontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.ui_display_regular, FontWeight.Normal),
        Font(R.font.ui_display_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
        Font(R.font.ui_text_semibolditalic, FontWeight.SemiBold)
    )
 
 ...

 Text(text = mainHeaderText, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 20.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 25.sp, fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal, fontFamily = fontFamily, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = textColor, maxLines = 1)

I've noticed that XML uses textSize whereas Compose uses FontSize; both are set to 25.sp, but they look significantly different if I scale the system font size to 2.0 in Accessibility.
XML TextView Version

Compose Text Version (ignore the subheader text)

Can someone explain to me the difference here, and how I can change the Compose Text version to match XML version as close as possible? Let me know if more code or information is needed.

to me it looks like the compose one has bold enabled whereas the "legacy" one doesn't...
